# browser.executeScript(return window.document.readyState) is not getting resolved in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to make my script to wait till web page is loaded completely for which I am using javascript expression "window.document.readyState" which will return "complete" if page is loaded completely.

```
function waitForWebpageLoadingCompletely(callback) {
try {
    var status="Incomplete";
    do {
        var flag = browser.executeScript("return window.document.readyState ;");
        //console.log(flag)
        flag.then(function (state) {
             console.log(state);
             if(state==="complete")
                 callback();
             else {
                 //status = "Incomplete";
                 console.log(state);
             }
         },function (err) {
             console.log(err)
         })


    }while(!(status ==="complete"));


} catch (e) {
    expect(false);
    console.log(e);
    callback();
}
```

}

But executeScript is not resolving to any success or error. Execution stops at this line. And after some time it gives below eror:
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: This is likely because you are calling an asynchronous method (`executeScript`) within a  synchronous loop.

Comment: @Florent B , What will be solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: have a look at [browser.wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait). Note that waiting for the `complete` state is useless given that the driver is already waiting for this state by default.

Comment: I am really confuse with this functionality of protractor that driver will wait by default. I have a scenario in which When i pass credentials and click on submit, dashboard loads. I just want to verify title is correct. Title displays properly when page loads completely. If driver waits till it loaded, title verification should pass always but it fails stating title not matched just after clicking submit. I am using callback to make it synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `browser.wait` - you mentioned in your comment that you needed to wait for the page title, so you will need to write something like this:

```
var WaitForPage = function(pageTitle, timeout = 30000){
  var deferred = promise.defer();
  browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){
    var el = element(by.cssContainingText('h1', pageTitle));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), timeout).then(function(){
      deferred.fulfill();
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

This function will wait up to 30000ms for an element of type `h1` that contains the specified `pageTitle` text. Change as appropriate to suit your situation and then call `WaitforPage('title')` before you continue.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually webdriver does that type of wait already out of the box. Not quite sure why you need to implement own pooling and waiting for document ready state.

If you working with some AngularJS/ReactJS or other SPA applications - this wait will give you actually nothing, since in such apps all the work are done after page is loaded and js starts to execute.

I would prefer to use suggestion of @m-hudson about using browser.wait() for some specific elements to appear.